# Use Gitlab Pipeline to push data to ftpserver

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy to a ftp server using a Gitlab pipeline. 
I tried this code:

```
deploy: // You can name your task however you like
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - master
        deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
```

But I get a error message. What is the best way to do this? :)

Comment: Try removing  `deploy:` after the `- master` line. That seems to be misplaced.

Comment: deploy: // You can name your task however you like
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - master
       
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp

I changed to this, but still does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it :)

```
  image: mwienk/docker-git-ftp


    deploy_all:
      stage: deploy
      script:
        - git config git-ftp.url "ftp://xx.nl:21/web/new.xxx.nl/public_html"
        - git config git-ftp.password "xxx"
        - git config git-ftp.user "xxxx"
        - git ftp init
        #- git ftp push  -m "Add new content"

      only:
        - master
```

Answer (score 26):

Then add the following code in your .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
variables:
  HOST: "example.com"
  USERNAME: "yourUserNameHere"
  PASSWORD: "yourPasswordHere"

deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror -Rnev ./public_html ./ --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
    - master
```

The above code will push all your recently modified files in your Gitlab repository into public_html folder in your FTP Server root.

Just update the variables HOST, USERNAME and PASSWORD with your FTP Credentials and commit this file to your Gitlab Repository, you are good to go.

Now whenever you make changes in your master branch, Gitlab will automatically push your changes to your remote FTP server.

Comment: I would advise against putting your credentials within the yml file as it may be exposed. Instead, go to Settings -> CI/CD -> (Click on) Variables -> set your HOST, PASSWORD, and USERNAME variables there. Then, you can reference them within the yml file as you mention, but, in this way, you don't run the risk of exposing them.

Comment: Which image do you use?

Answer (score 1):

try this. There's a CI Lint tool in Gitlab that helps with formatting errors. The linter was showing an error, the additional deploy statement.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master

  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -v ./ $FTP_DESTINATION --reverse --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master
```